# React tabs - switching destroys component, need to maintain the same component

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I am trying to make a multi-tabbed SPA with React and Material-UI. I use code from this demo as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qlq1j47l2w

It appears that if I follow the aforementioned example, I end up returning new instance of the component with tab contents each time I navigate between the tabs:

```
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        scrollable
        scrollButtons="auto"
      >
        <Tab label="Tab 1" />
        <Tab label="Tab 2" />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
    {value === 0 && <Tab1Contents/>}
    {value === 1 && <Tab2Contents/>}
```

As Tab1Contents is a form, I would like its internal state to be retained, instead of loading a new instance of the component, which the code above appears to do.

What is the best way to get React to use only one instance of the component and 'memorise field values'?

**EDIT**

I have added Redux to the example, but the store corresponding to the form within the Tab is destroyed the moment I switch away. Is there any other way to implement tabs in React that would hide the tab contents, instead of destroying them and re-creating them from scratch each time I navigate away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to my problem was quite simple! If you don't want to destroy the component (remove it from DOM), you can simply hide it!

Instead of:

```
{value === 0 && <Tab1Contents/>}
```

Use:

```
<div style={{ display: value === 0? 'block': 'none'}}>
    <Tab1Contents/>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed all the <TabPanel> components and just used this solution. Does the  <TabPanel> component do anything fancy other than remove the body of the hidden tabs?

Comment: @shawn98ag I have looked it up, and it appears to be part of the convention existing for the assistive technologies: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel How many assistive apps rely on it in reality is an open question, but it is mentioned as part of the contract..

Answer (score 5):

It was already mentioned that you have to prevent your component from being removed from the DOM. The easiest solution with MUI5 TabPanel is in fact to just replace

```
{value === index && children}
```

with

```
{children}
```

that means your Tabpanel would look like that:

```
import * as React from "react";


const TabPanel= ({ children, value, index, ...other }) => {

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {children}
      {/* {value === index && children} // This was removed */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TabPanel;
```

No additional logic necessary as the hidden prop already takes care of the visibility aspect. This way your components should maintain their state!

Comment: Nice one! It's an old question, but thanks for chipping in with an updated info for v5

Answer (score 1):

You would need to persist the state between the tab changes. I prototyped a form using React forms [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for `Tab1Container` and as you play around with it, the value will disappear

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ojwhr

What you ideally need to use something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which will use a `store` to keep the information even between the state changes like `Tab` clicks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there no 'Singleton' pattern that can be used with components? I have heard of Redux, and may actually have to resort to that, if there isn't a simpler solution. Thank you

Comment: Actually, this doesn't answer my question. Ihave added Redux to link it to the form values, and the moment I switch away from the tab, the corresponding part of the Redux store is destroyed.

Comment: Could you share the codesandbox link to reproduce the issue? I don't think that Redux can't solve this problem. I have done it multiple times

Comment: Posted the solution :) It is so simple it made me laugh